# How do I configure Squid Proxy located at a different location to route internet traffic?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid, access-control-list

I have a Linux box (Ubuntu 9.10) at a different location. I installed squid proxy and tried using that IP and port (opened 3128 at that location) in Firefox. I can't get it to work.

My current scenario :

- The current location ISP's IP is 72.87.54.XX
- Each machine in the network has the IP range 192.168.0.0/104

In `/etc/squid/squid.conf` : how would I configure this part in acl :

```
acl internal_network src 192.168.0.0/104
http_access allow internal_network
```

Where would I put the actual IP 72.87.54.XX in the squid.conf file to be allowed for internet traffic at the remote location?

Comment: Define 'doesn't work'.  Do you get squid access denied pages or what?  If you do a tcpdump on the squid box do you see the incoming requests for port 3128?  What do you see in the squid cache/access logs?

Comment: BTW You know that Ubuntu 9.10 is no longer supported right?  You should seriously consider updating, so you can receive security patches.

Comment: Yeah, we will have to place an update request for the latest version of Ubuntu. Checked the logs, I see the IP from the remote location where a test machine was used to check Squid. It worked at the remote location but not from my location. I don't get a Squid denied access page either.

Comment: 192.168.0.0/104 isn't a valid IPv4 address range as there are only 32 bits in the address (rather than the 104+ implied by your netmask). Is that a typo?

Answer (score -1):

You will want an extra couple of lines like this:

```
acl office_network src 72.87.54.0/104
http_access allow office_network
```

The name "office_network" is arbitrary and should match whatever makes sense for what the IP addresses are used for.

The `/104` is not what I'm used to seeing.  This is normally `/24` which represents an IPv4 netmask covering the first three octets and leaving the last one free.

Comment: Actually, on reading your question again, I'm not sure which of the IP addresses is the Squid server and which is your office.  Could you clarify?

Comment: Squid server has a different IP like 31.101.xx.xx port 3128 open. My office : Comcast's IP is 72.87.54.xx. I thought 72.87.54.0/104 is supposed to be the range. 24 makes sense. Will try...

Comment: This didn't work either :( I am kinda lost on the config file!

Comment: Does your firewall allow inbound connections from 72.87.54.0/24 on port 3128?