# Fast EC2 micro AMI which can enable graphical remote logon?

Tags: amazon-ec2, remote-access, amazon-ami, nx

I am currently using Natty_FreeNx_RubyRails (ami-6754970e) and it can be a little slow when browsing simple websites remotely. Before going to a 'small' instance, I would like to know if we can optimize this AMI further to make work a bit faster without any sluggishness with the micro instance.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Are you trying to get a remote desktop to look at websites through the Amazon instance?  "remote login" for a linux box can also mean any command line environment, and the smallest available AMI can do that.

Comment: Why in the world would a Rails server require a GUI? All of the action is at the command line!

Answer (score 2):

If you refer to the [Ubuntu system requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) for current versions, you will note that:

- For a desktop installation with GUI components installed, the requirement is 1024 megabytes (1 GB) of RAM.
- A server installation with CLI access only requires only 128 megabytes (1/8 GB) of RAM.

Micro Instances have 613 megabytes of RAM. Yes, Ubuntu Desktop will run on a machine with less than one gigabyte, but it is unlikely to perform well with less than the minimum required resources.

For "normal" performance, you need to use a system that meets the minimum requirements. This can be achieved either by reducing the amount of RAM required (i.e. using a CLI-only operating system that requires less RAM), or by increasing the amount of RAM available.

Comment: Definitely makes sense! I wish there is an AMI that has desktop capabilities with remote login (NX) enabled without all the bells and whistles. Just want it to browse the internet via Chrome/Firefox for sites that are slower from my IP.

Comment: @ThinkCode The desktop capabilities *are* the bells and whistles.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're only using this for browsing.  Why not just setup a proxy?  Something like squid will run just fine on a micro instance, and you could use your regular desktop browser environment.

Just remember to limit squid to either user a username/password or limited to your IP (otherwise you'll run a free proxy for the entire internet).

Comment: That was my first bet too : I tried various guides but failed everytime : http://serverfault.com/questions/346600/how-do-i-configure-squid-proxy-located-at-a-different-location-to-route-internet

Comment: @ThinkCode Strongly recommend mindset adjustment: failing at implementing a simple solution to a problem is not a good reason to move on to a more complex solution.

Comment: @MilesErickson : Trust me, I don't give up that easily! I tried what I thought should fix the issue and it didn't. Remote desktop works for now for my needs, hence trying to fine-tune it.

Comment: @ThinkCode Sysadmins are like Marines: we don't *give up*, we *escalate*.

Comment: I am not a Sysadmin. I am a programmer. We don't have a Sysadmin that I can escalate this to.